# Department structure treeview passing argument to fetch employees (MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following problem: I am making an MVC intranet website for the corporation I'm working for. One part of the job is to make a phonebook - I need a tree like structure of the departments (with depth).

I have a view with two div elements - left (containing the departments, the structure follows below), and a right div which should show all the employees that are working in the selected (clicked) department.

```
@helper GetTree(List<PhonesClasses.Department> department, int parentID){
foreach(var i in department.Where(a=>a.headDepartmentID.Equals(parentID)))
{        
    {var childDepartments = department.Where(a => a.headDepartmentID.Equals(i.departmentID)).Count();

    if(childDepartments > 0)
    {
        <li class="haschlid" id="@i.departmentID">
            <a href="#">@i.departmentName</a>
            <ul class="sub-dep">
                @GetTree(department, @i.departmentID)
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li id="@i.departmentID">
             <a href="#">@i.departmentName</a>
        </li>
    } 
  }       
}
```

The following is the above-mentioned view. As you can see, I had the idea to make a partial view but I'm not sure I'm headed in the right direction.

```
<div class ="containerStructure">
        <div class="leftDivStructure">
            @if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)           
            {
                 <ul class="list" id="deplist">
                      @Treeview.GetTree(Model, Model.FirstOrDefault().headDepartmentID)
                </ul>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="rightDivStructure">
            Employee
            @*@Html.Partial("_PeopleInDepartment", new {depID =  Model.departmentID()})*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

My employee and department classes both have DepartmentID fields, so when a department is clicked on in my tree view, a parameter () should be passed to the partial view, or whatever needs to be there to handle the parameter and show the employees. Below is the controller that I think has to fetch the result.

```
public ActionResult PeopleInDepartment(int depID)
        {
            List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();
            peopleList = Persons.GetPersons(depID);
            return View(peopleList);
        }
```

For further clarifications please comment!

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Are you asking if this is a good approach?

Comment: Yes, that's was my idea but I can't make it work. Is this a good approach and how can I pass the departmentID parameter to my partial view?